# Should I use aliases or modify $PATH?

Tags: bash, bashrc

A made a bash file called `foo`, containing a few instruction and I often use it. I want to call it using `$ foo`

I could either add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/foo` to `~/.bashrc`

Or add `alias foo='path/to/foo'` in `~/.bash_aliases`

Is there a fundamental difference between these two choices?

Comment: Suppose you are using ubuntu. If there is a folder `bin` in your home directory, this will be added to the PATH when you log in (defined in `$HOME/.profile`). So just copy `foo` to `$HOME/bin/foo` or create a link there: `ln -s /path/to/foo $HOME/bin/foo`.

Comment: link should be better. So definitively not the allias ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you choose is ultimately your freedom. Both options can work.

However, I would rather prefer a **third approach**. Create a folder "bin" or a folder ".local/bin" in your home folder, and place your custom executables, or a symbolic link to them, there. Either of these folders will, in Ubuntu, automatically be included in your path.

The "alias" system is rather aimed to simplify lengthy commands, e.g. call a program always with specific options (eg `ls=`ls --color`). Indeed, it can be used if you wish to avoid having to type a path to an executable that is not in your search PATH. Such alias, however, will not work from within a script, or from a hotkey definition, etc..

Of course, you can also adapt your PATH. However, conceptually, that is not the best way to work. It would become unwieldy to continue working this way to accommodate executables that are stored in yet a different folder. Dropping an executable or a link to it in a folder already defined in the PATH is a far better option.

Comment: If `foo` is meant to be used system-wide and not only for a particular user, you should also consider copying it to `/usr/local/bin`.